# App installed size is different on Same devices Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

When I installed my same apk in 2 nexus devices, both shows different installation size.

1) In my Manifest also I added `android:installLocation="auto"`.

2) Both got installed in device memory

Thanks for prompt response.

[image]
[image]

Comment: same problem for `android:installLocation="internalOnly"` ?

Comment: But my app should support both internal and external installation. So only i added android:installLocation="auto" .

Comment: you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to many factors, one of which Android 6.0's new way of handling newly installed apps; it kind of decodes a lot of the code before runtime and saves it thus it takes more space in the storage, but when running, it doesn't have to do all the processing all over again.

And their exists more factors to consider. Anyway, there is nothing to worry about as this is very normal. Try checking PlayStore on the web from a PC and look down for the size of the apk , mostly you'll find "Size varies between devices".

Regards.

Comment: Thanks. But my both Nexus having same Android OS and same configurations.  So i got confused how its happening.?